# Need to equate more than one property in criteria on joining the tables

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, restriction

I need to implement the following code using criteria.

```
left join A a ON a.id = o.id
        and a.rules_id = b.id 
        and a.global_id = gd.id
        WHERE  m.org_name = 'PQR'
```

But when I am adding a criteria like this

```
 criteria = criteria.createAlias("a", "a", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
                    Restrictions.eqProperty("a.id", "b.id")).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a.rules_id", "b.id")).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a.global_id", "gd.id"));
```

it is going in the where clause of the query as follows:

```
  left join A a ON a.id = o.id
        WHERE  m.org_name = 'PQR'  and a.rules_id = b.id 
        and a.global_id = gd.id
```

Can anyone help me with the correct code what can be done so that the join condition will be correct?

I tried with this:

```
criteria = criteria.createAlias("a", "a", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
                    Restrictions.eqProperty("a.id", "b.id")).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a.rules_id", "b.id")).add(Restrictions.eqProperty("a.global_id", "gd.id"));
```

Need this kind of query:

```
left join A a ON a.id = o.id
        and a.rules_id = b.id 
        and a.global_id = gd.id
        where  m.org_name = 'PQR'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use restriction conjunction in this scenario.

```
criteria = criteria.createAlias("a", "a", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
                Restrictions.conjunction(
                Restrictions.eqProperty("a.id","o.id"),
                Restrictions.eqProperty("a.rules_id", "b.id")));
```